# dhtmlxScheduler - new properties in events table

Tags: dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I'm trying to enhance your table "events" but so far I have failed. I use yii framework, and when you add to the table a new field, for example "about", "worker", "client" when adding a new event, I don't see what would these fields appear in the form... While in the method "actionScheduler_data" I have clearly spelled out the line

```
$scheduler->render_table("events","event_id", "start_date, end_date, event_name, worker, client, rec_type,event_pid,event_length, event_about");
```

Help me pls!

Answer (score 0):

The component does not add controls automaticaly, you need to redefine configuration of the form http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/lightbox_editors.html